# Authorize requests dynamically in spring-security

Tags: spring-security

Many of the examples I have seen authorize requests by hard-coding or XML config:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize                                  
            .mvcMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()         
            .mvcMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                             
            .mvcMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")   
            .anyRequest().denyAll()                                                
        );
}
```

But for many systems, shouldn't this information be stored in a database-like storage?

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .rulesFromDB(...)                      // This is the most common situation, right?
    );
}
```

Of course, spring-security does not have such a method.
Does spring-security provide other mechanisms for dynamic authorization?

In order to become familiar with spring's dynamic authorization mechanism, is it a good start point to learn `SecurityMetadataSource` and its implementations in spring-security?